# facebook login working on localhost but not on server codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using facebook login in codeigniter and when i run localhost project its working fine but when i upload files on my server its not working . I changed my SITE URL and DOMAIN NAME from facebook developer but still facing the issue.
I found many article from google but did not resolve it.

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class User_Authentication extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        // Load facebook library
        $this->load->library('facebook');

        //Load user model
        $this->load->model('user');
    }

    public function index(){
        $userData = array();

        // Check if user is logged in
        if($this->facebook->is_authenticated()){
            // Get user facebook profile details
            $userProfile = $this->facebook->request('get', '/me?fields=id,first_name,last_name,email,gender,locale,picture');

            // Preparing data for database insertion
            $userData['oauth_provider'] = 'facebook';
            $userData['oauth_uid'] = $userProfile['id'];
            $userData['first_name'] = $userProfile['first_name'];
            $userData['last_name'] = $userProfile['last_name'];
            $userData['email'] = $userProfile['email'];
            $userData['gender'] = $userProfile['gender'];
            $userData['locale'] = $userProfile['locale'];
            $userData['profile_url'] = 'https://www.facebook.com/'.$userProfile['id'];
            $userData['picture_url'] = $userProfile['picture']['data']['url'];

            // Insert or update user data
            $userID = $this->user->checkUser($userData);

            // Check user data insert or update status
            if(!empty($userID)){
                $data['userData'] = $userData;
                $this->session->set_userdata('userData',$userData);
            } else {
               $data['userData'] = array();
            }

            // Get logout URL
            $data['logoutUrl'] = $this->facebook->logout_url();
        }else{
            $fbuser = '';

            // Get login URL
            $data['authUrl'] =  $this->facebook->login_url();
        }

        // Load login & profile view
        $this->load->view('user_authentication/index',$data);
    }

    public function logout() {
        // Remove local Facebook session
        $this->facebook->destroy_session();
        // Remove user data from session
        $this->session->unset_userdata('userData');
        // Redirect to login page
        redirect('user_authentication');
    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure your file names and class **only** have the first letter upper case the rest lower case.

Comment: yes i checked it and there is no issue of file names

Comment: I think its the issue of SITE URL and DOMAIN NAME on facebook developer ->setting. but when i change it and put live server details its not working and when i put localhost details its working fine on localhost